# How to create a standalone exe using python 3.4

Tags: exe, cx-freeze, python-3.4

I have created an exe file using cx_freeze (python 3.4).
Along with the exe there is a library.zip,python34.dll and some .pyd file with it.How can i create a standalone exe so that it can be run on other systems where python is not installed.

A single exe file is all i want.Can this be achieved...??
This question was asked previously as well but i didnt find any suitable solutions in it.Help please.

Thanks

Comment: cx_Freeze doesn't do that directly, but there are some workarounds you can use. See the FAQ: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables

Comment: thnx @Thomas....one more thing....does py2exe work with python3..its like in most of the comments i read that only cx_freeze  works with python3....any idea regarding this?

Comment: Yes, cx_Freeze is the only one of these tools that supports Python 3 properly. There was some work on Python 3 support in py2exe (called py3exe), and PyInstaller has an issue open for Python 3 support, but I don't think either of them are ready to use.

Comment: My own tool, [Pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) also supports Python 3, but that makes installers, not single exes.

Comment: @ThomasK i used py2nsis and it worked really well in creating a single exe....atleast this works with python 3.....

Comment: Great, glad something worked. Do you mean py2nsis or pynsist? Both exist, but it doesn't look like py2nsis works on Python 3.

Comment: Py2Nsis worked pretty good with python 3...didnt use pynsist....

Comment: Weird, looking at the code, it doesn't look like it should work with Python 3. How did you install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first .pyd files are python native extensions written in either C or C++ for windows target platform. Next in order to get exe built you will going to need to have pyinstaller package installed (http://www.pyinstaller.org/). You can install it using either "pip install pyinstaller", "easy_install pyinstaller" or just specify it as a dependency within REQUIREMENTS.TXT or SETUP.PY of yours. But this package depends on pywin32 package which can only be installed either manually or with easy_install. It doen't support pip because the only bundle that is available is - exe file format. easy_install handles it though.

Comment: thnx @Zorgiev....somehow pyinstaller package is nt gettting installed in my system...while unpacking it using easy_install pyinstaller an error is popping up syntaxerror: invalid syntax....think pyinstaller doesnt work with python 3.4....

Comment: I beg my pardon. I didn't note you specified python 3.4. I work only with python up to 2.7.